# Prevent call a public method from an extended class

Tags: java, swing

I created a custom component which extended from `JTextField`. I want to prevent calling `getText()` method from my component. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override it, provide a dummy implementation (or just `throw UnsupportedOperationException`) and mark it as `@Deprecated`.

Comment: I don't think `@Deprecated` is appropriate here.

Comment: Why not? If a method is marked as deprecated, you still can make callbacks to it, but there isn't any guarantee that you won't experience any problems for that decision.

Comment: Because the method isn't "deprecated", it's just not supported. You're using that annotation for something it's not meant to be used for.

Comment: ^ The method is deprecated in that case. So yes, @Deprecated is needed.

Comment: @Makky No, it isn't. See [How and When to Deprecate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Override it and throw [UnsupportedOperationexception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) in method body or just leave it empty.

Throwing exception will guarantee you that this method is never used since you'll be getting exceptions otherwise and fix.

Answer (score 2):

Throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) in the method. There is no way to disallow calling `getText()` at compile-time, so the runtime exception is the best alternative.

Additionally, from a documentation standpoint, it would be wise to clearly state (in the Javadocs, presumably) that `getText()` is not supported by your class. That's really the best warning you can give - it's the responsibility of whoever is using your class to ensure that they fully understand how it works before using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
@Override
@Deprecated //will allow caller to see that calling this method should not be called
public void someMethod(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not supported");

}
```

Comment: Again, `@Deprecated` is not appropriate here.

Comment: Just used for visual cue

Comment: It shouldn't be: `@Deprecated` should only be used in specific circumstances (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html)).

Comment: Those are just guidelines and meant to be broken and so here IMO it can be used.

Comment: *"meant to be broken"* What's the point of even having them, then?

Comment: @arshajii it is just an opinion. You can differ in it if you want. Made sense to me so used it.

Answer (score 1):

Override it with a dummy implementation and add documentation mentioning `Not to be used!` or throw an exception from inside.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what are you trying to do, but if what you want is that nothing happens when you call getText, just override it and make it return empty string or nothing. It might help if you explain a bit more of what are you after.

EDIT: just read your comment, then do both. @Override and @Deprecated :)

Comment: i want to show a warning or something else to the programmer like "dont use it!". Or if possible maybe show as a deprecated method.

Comment: You can do both, "@Deprecated and @Override" together ;)

Answer (score 1):

Calling the getText cannot be prevented, as you cannot reduce visibility on override, so you can choose any other option, like returning a null value or throwing an exception like UnsupportedOperationException, explaining in the javadoc, what is the method doing.

The problem with either solution is if you are using a JTextField variable you might be expecting the getText() method to return something else

```
JTextField textField = new YourTextField();
textField.getText(); //--> might throw an UnsupportedOperationException instead of NullPointerException (as the javadoc says)
```